# How to reuse the result of a SPARQL subquery in 4store?

Tags: sparql

I modelled the songs of an album as follows:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix md: <http://example.com/music-discography#> .

md:album1 md:songs-of-album md:song1 .
md:album1 md:songs-of-album md:song2 .
md:album1 md:songs-of-album md:song3 .

md:song1 md:name "Song 1" .
md:song2 md:name "Song 2" .
md:song3 md:name "Song 3" .

md:song1 md:position "1"^^xsd:integer .
md:song2 md:position "2"^^xsd:integer .
md:song3 md:position "3"^^xsd:integer .
```

I would like to be able to access the name of the last song of an album.

Therefore I thought about first getting the `md:position` of the last song by calculating how many songs an album contains

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?lastposition)
WHERE {
  { md:album1 md:songs-of-album ?songInnerQuery }
}
```

which produces the correct result "3":

```
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="lastposition">
    <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">3</literal>
    </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
```

I then wanted to reuse this result by using the query above as a subquery. How can I do this? I tried the following:

```
SELECT ?songName WHERE {

  ?song md:position ?lastposition .
  ?song md:name ?songName

  { SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?lastposition)
    WHERE {
      { md:album1 md:songs-of-album ?songInnerQuery }
    }
  }

}
```

However, this does not work and yields all three songs:

```
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="songName"><literal>Song 3</literal></binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="songName"><literal>Song 2</literal></binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="songName"><literal>Song 1</literal></binding>
    </result>
  </results>
```

Why does this happen and what is the correct way of doing this? I am using the triplestore [4store](http://4store.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug in 4store.  You should probably report it to them.  The results you get with Jena are what you'd expect:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="songName"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="songName">
        <literal>Song 3</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>
```

But, you don't need a subquery to do this.  You could take the song that has a position such that there are no songs with greater position:

```sql
SELECT ?songName WHERE {
  ?song md:position ?lastposition .
  ?song md:name ?songName

  filter not exists {
    ?song_ md:position ?position
    filter (?position > ?lastposition)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative solution. Will upvote as soon as I have enough reputation. Unfortunately 4store does not seem to support this: _parser error: syntax error, unexpected NOT on line 9_. Or I am doing something wrong. I will try to get in touch with them regarding both cases.

Comment: @nistel In 2013, it looks like "filter not exists" wasn't supported yet ([Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/4store-support/k0ny4w8nZ9w)).  The workaround there was to use "minus".  I don't know if that would work in this case, though.

Comment: Thank you Joshua for pointing this out. The query executes but no binding for songName is returned. I opened a thread over there (not approved yet).